# Need to convert/import Lotus Notes Knowledge Base Document Repository Helpdesk Database

Tags: conversion, database, lotus-notes

I have a Lotus Notes Database that is a knowledge base for a helpdesk function.

We no longer have a Notes environment, nor even a copy of Lotus Notes to stick on a machine and run.

I have kept a copy of the database but now need to convert it or import it into another format to run the same.

We have Sharepoint Portal server 2003 and Sharepoint 2010 Foundation so if it could be converted into that it would be ideal, we also have SQL Server 2005.

I do not know SQL so the database was a really quick way for someone with no SQL knowledge to setup and just go.

Cost is a factor in this and if it costs any money to convert/import this I will need to setup from scratch.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the lack of response I'm guessing there is no way of doing it without a cost of migration to an alternative system. Closing Question As No solution.